# Squarespace - CSS change placeholder text color

Tags: css, forms, squarespace

i'm really struggling to find away to change the color of the placeholder text within my form fields.

I can change the background color of the form fields but not the color of the text.

The placeholder text does not stand out enough when the background color is anything but white.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, if you want change placeholder text color;

```
<style>
::placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
 color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
 color: red;
}
</style>
```